# Deep learning of Models!

Tags: machine-learning

With the advent of Machine Learning, Big data and Artificial Network can models learn over a period of time to take its own decisions?

Comment: It is possible that sometime in the future, the fitting of models for only predictive purposes on a completely understood data pipeline will be automated.  This would leave the other 90% of the job in human hands.

Comment: Not until there is strong AI. At which point, basically everything will be automated.

Comment: @MatthewDrury the key components for that type of automation are already out there at the moment.

Comment: See [What do statisticians do that can't be automated?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22572/17230). And "threat" seems to imply a rather pessimistic view of technological progress.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the greatest part can be automated (and already is) :

- **Fitting (cross validating) the model**

Many R packages or Python's sk-learn do it quite well.

- **Encoding the variables**

The factors (per example) can be viewed as dummy variables / integers / mean response of the target and sent to a cross validated model. Thus allowing to choose the best encoding of the features (with respect to the CV score)

- **Selecting the best subset of variables**

Is really easy to automate as well.

But...

- Given the current time needed to train the models (the process presented above is really time consuming), some opinion based choices are necessary
- **The metric** to optimize is a human decision
- **Feature engineering** is hard to automate (and often needs a domain knowledge)

And this second part is usually the one that takes most time...